# Inequalities with both x and y

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

If I had an equation like $b^x>$  $d^y$ where $b,d $ are real, and wanted to find out when it is true, for finitely many $+ve$ integer values of $x,y$, I would start by writing $z = b^x$ and $z=d^y$ then on separate graphs draw them, first one $z$ against $x$, second one $z$ against $y$, then see if one graph is always greater than the other one for some finite range of $x$ and $y$ values (I fixed $0<b<1$ and $d>1$, however doing this approach gets me the wrong answer, as it is clear that $a^x$ is never greater than $d^y$ for $+ve$ integers $x,y$, however if I plot $y=b^x$ and then $x=d^y$ I get a finite region where $b^x$ is greater.
Which approach is correct?[image]
In the picture you can see the first graph is never above the second one for positive $x,y$.

Comment: What’s +ve mean?

Comment: more than $0$, positive.

Comment: If $b>1$ you can let x go off to infinity and get infinitely many solutions. Same if $d<1$.  If $b\leq 1$ and $d\geq 1$, you get no solutions.

Comment: Apparently there is a finite number of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ which satisfy the inequality when $b<1$ and $d>1$. This can be seen by plotting $y=b^x$ and $x=d^y$ on the same axis, but once again I cannot find out why this is allowed/true, even more so frustrating as you seem to be having the same issue as me.

Comment: Can someone validate this claim please?

Comment: 0 is a finite number.